# Ruby strptime %Y returning wrong date/year

Tags: ruby, date

I have a method that returns date in the format I want to have it. I work with calendar weeks, so I don't save them as dates and convert them in the method to display them nicely in the view (when necessary).

Anyway, this is the method:

```
def formatted_date(year, week, day)
  Date.strptime("#{year}-#{week}-#{day}", '%Y-%V-%u')
end
```

When type in `formatted_date(2022, 47, 21)` it returns the date for today, but when I type in `formatted_date(2023, 47, 21)` it also returns the day for today, not for 2023.

Why is that? And how do i do it correctly? I thought it just returns the year with four digits which is the case here, right?

Comment: Try with '%G-%V-%u' format (the formatter for a week-based year is G not Y)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov thank you! I didn't realize week-based year would be any different if I give '2023' as a parameter. if you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing the wrong format to `strptime` which is why the year isn't changing. Do something like this:

```
def formatted_date(date)
  DateTime.strptime(date, "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%W")
end
```

Pass the date format like this `formatted_date("21-02-2022")` and you will get the result in the format you are looking for. Obviously, you can change `strftime("%Y-%m-%W")` the way you want to.